# Producing tasks on-demand in producer-consumer pattern

Tags: java, concurrency, queue

Let's consider the following situation in producer-consumer pattern:

I cannot wait with a task to be performed. I want to produce task on demand (eg. with `Supplier`) when a consumer is ready to process it. In `SynchronousQueue` I need to have actual task when executing `put()` method. How to solve my problem?

I know that I could solve it by design - just make a set of workers and tell them to produceTask-consume-Task-repeat, but I'm looking for another way.

To be more specific:
Let's consider that I have remote http resource A. I can get a 'task' from it to process in my worker threads. Results are sent asynchronously. But the thing is that I should not get a task from A if I am not able to process it right now.

Comment: what tasks are you talking about? The "producer-consumer pattern" does not include tasks. Both producer and consumer are supposed to be threads.

Comment: By tasks I mean chunk of data to process. In my case it's a task because it is a bunch of inctructions to execute, but it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I want to produce task on demand (eg. with Supplier) when a consumer is ready to process it."
One example of producing data on demand is [Reactive Streams](https://www.reactive-streams.org/) protocol, where `Subscriber` (consumer) requests `Publisher` (producer) to push next chunk of data with `Subscription.request()` method.

This protocol is implemented in RxJava and other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If I were You, in the case of "producer-consumer pattern" you should not use blocking queues, however You looking for a non-blocking asynchronous queue.

Then everybody notified just in time.

Or is there any other constraint with the actual tasks. Or somehow I misunderstand You? Which side of the producer-consumer goes hungry?

Comment: Otherwise You have to pay attention to the classical concurrent programming problems, which has some relevance in our case, like here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronous-queue

Comment: I've added more details in question description.

Comment: "But the thing is that I should not get a task from A if I am not able to process it right now.": Are you talking about expectation or symptom? I mean what is our goal or problem here?

1. Are you talking about A send a task to consume, when should not, then ensure to lock out consuming, when the consumer is busy.
2. Or are you talking about the scenario when you have to wait the tasks on consumer side to consumer be ready? In that kind of communication you should already have a fifo queue where possible to any task to wait.

Comment: I'm talking about expectation. Producing a "task" is blocking operation. I want to produce new task when there is a free worker to pick it.
I could have `ThreadPoolExecutor` and separate thread with infinite loop checking if `ThreadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount() < ThreadPoolExecutor.getPoolSize()`, but that would be CPU consuming and adding `Thread.sleep()` would add unnecessary latency.

Comment: By the way, the sophisticated way is the Reactive Streams pattern mentioned Alexei above.

Comment: I'd probably go this way but it requires more refactoring in my current code. I'm using RxJS very exensively with good results.